# Bootstrap 4 library bootstrap.js and bootstrap dropdown lists are mutually exclusive

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

I am using Bootstrap 4, and trying to use bootstrap.js in order to show/hide a modal using Javascript. However, whenever I include bootstrap.js into my project the Bootstrap 4 dropdown list stops opening the list in order to select elements.

I tried not adding bootstrap.js and the dropdown lists start working normally, but by following this approach I have no way of opening a modal programmatically.

The order by which I load all the libraries is:

```
      "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
      "node_modules/vue/dist/vue.js",
      "node_modules/@svgdotjs/svg.js/dist/svg.js",
      "node_modules/@svgdotjs/svg.draggable.js/dist/svg.draggable.js",
      "wwwroot/site.js",
      "node_modules/@aspnet/signalr/dist/browser/signalr.js",
      "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js",
```

I expect to include bootstrap.js and allow both, dropdown lists and the command $("#myModal").modal("show") to work.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround by not importing the whole bootstrap.js library but instead importing only util.js and modal.js (which both can be found inside bootstrap/js/dist). This way the problem was solved for now, however I don't understand what caused the problem in the first place.